# Xcode Storyboard Modal Transitions & Orientation

Tags: xcode4, model, ios5, transition

So i am fairly new to xcode and loving it so far. I am having a problem adding a new transition between 2 views/scenes in xcode

So i have added the new view to my master detail application and would like the transition to be modal and to be form based. I am having a problem getting my head around the 3 areas where you can add/change the transition of the scene.

I am trying to create a transition similar to the one found in the default apple application when you reply/create a new email.

Currently My application when in landscape and correct button is clicked Jumps to portrait mode and displays my new scene for no reason i can see.

My new scene contains a seague,navigation controller and the scene itself. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally figured it out after much playing... I changed the seague to style: modal, presentation: Page sheet, Tansition:Default. So working as expected